# $\mathcal{N}=4$ SUSY in $d=3$ versus $\mathcal{N}=2$ in $d=4$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

Which is the field content of the hypermultiplet and the vector multiplet in $\mathcal{N}=4 \ d=3$ Supersymmmetry?

Is it correct to state that $\mathcal{N}=4$ in $d=3$ has $8$ supercharges, (since there are $4$ minimum dimension spinors, and the lowest dimensional representation of $SO(1,2)$ has real dimension 2), is completely equivalent to $\mathcal{N}=2$ in $d=4$ (where I have $2$ Weyl spinors of $SO(1,3)$ each of real dimension $4$), which also has $8$ supercharges, and therefore the multiplets in those two cases are completely identical?

Comment: There is a short description at the end of the page $5$ of this [paper](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/01f/396T/table.pdf)